# How to display a child's many to many attribute in a parent model's list_display in django

Tags: python, django

I have a parent model defined as :

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    number =  models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    def services(self):
       return  self.service_set.filter(purchaseorder=self.pk)
```

Child model Service is defined as :

```
class Service(models.Model):
    purchaseorder = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder)
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module)

    def get_modules(self):
        return self.modules.all()
```

There is another model Module having M2M relation with the Service model. I wish to display the modules as a list in the Parent model change_list view i.e in list_display list. How do I do that? What is the effect on the number of database hits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example, I do something like this

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def get_modules(self):
        return ', '.join([module.FIELD for service.modules.all() in self.service_set.filter(purchaseorder=self.pk) for module in service.modules.all()])
```

then in admin.py

```
class PurchaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('number', 'get_modules')

admin.site.register(Service, ServiceAdmin)
```

I'm not sure about the db hits but you can use a tool like [django-debug-toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar) to see the SQL queries generated before and after you implement it.

**UPDATED BASED ON COMMENT**

Try the above list comprehension and see if it works? You might need to play around with the output a bit to get it right in shell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/131238/super9 I want to display the module list in PurchaseOrderAdmin, not in ServiceAdmin.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/users/131238/super9 tried the list comprehension, by using the following also, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Django Version: 1.2.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Caught TypeError while rendering: sequence item 0: expected string, list found  , after that I changed the above list comprehension to return ', '.join([module.name for module in service.modules.all() for service in self.service_set.filter(purchaseorder=self.pk)])  for which I get the error :emplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Caught UnboundLocalError while rendering: local variable 'service' referenced before assignment

Comment: try `return ', '.join([service.modules.all() for service in self.service_set.filter(purchaseorder=self.pk)])`

Comment: Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Caught TypeError while rendering: sequence item 0: expected string, QuerySet found

Comment: `return [service.modules.all() for service in self.service_set.filter(purchaseorder=self.pk)]`

Comment: Thx a lot  super9, bit the o/p [[]] is an embedded list. Can't use ', '.join. Why?

Comment: Because `join` is a string method and we're returning a queryset.
Try this: `return ', '.join([module.FIELD for service.modules.all() in self.service_set.filter(purchaseorder=self.pk) for module in service.modules.all()])`. Also, please upvote and accept the answer if you found it helpful :D

Comment: Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value: 
can't assign to function call (models.py, line ...